# Поведение таблиц в Lua при присваивании

Tags: lua

Я новичок в lua, и для меня не очевидно такое поведение:

```
local a = {
  name = "A",
  counter = 0
}

function a:say ()
  self.counter = self.counter + 1
  print(self.name..": "..self.counter)
end

local b = a
b.name = "B"

a:say() -- результат B: 1 -- ожидалось A: 1
a:say() -- результат B: 2 -- ожидалось A: 2
a:say() -- результат B: 3 -- ожидалось A: 3
b:say() -- результат B: 4 -- ожидалось B: 1
```

Как мне скопировать новый экземпляр таблицы, а не наследовать от старой?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В луа таблицы при присваивании не копируются,`a` и `b` - cсылки на таблицу, одну и ту же. Чтоб создать новую таблицу вам надо реализовать функцию копирования и использовать ее:

```
function table.copy (originalTable)
 local copyTable = {}
  for k,v in pairs(originalTable) do
    copyTable[k] = v
  end
 return copyTable
end

local b = table.copy(a)
```

Comment: Ругается: attempt to call a nil value (field 'copy'). Версия Луа 5.3.4

Comment: стандартной функции такой нет, сейчас дополню ответ

Comment: Ага, нагуглил уже [вот эту ссылку](http://lua-users.org/wiki/CopyTable) спасибо!